# How to add directory location to mysql varchar?

Tags: c#, mysql, directory

When I do query and I add the location string example: "'`C:\SomeFolder\SubFolder\image.jpg`'",
the query sets the value in database as "'`C:SomeFolderSubFolderimagejpg`'" then I found that to save location you need to have two `'\'` characters, (like this `\\`) for it to be counted as a directory location, so can you make me a string function that you enter the location and the function returns the same string but with doubled backslashes?

```
input = 'C:\SomeFolder\SubFolder\image.jpg';
database need to save as 'C:\\SomeFolder\\SubFolder\\image.jpg';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace all slashes with double-slashes:

```
string input = @"C:\SomeFolder\SubFolder\image.jpg";
string query = input.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

Comment: string query = input.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace(@"\\\\",@"\\");

Comment: It's simpler than that: `Replace(@"\+", @"\\")`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public string EscapePathSeparators(string path)
{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var segment in path.Split(new char[]{ ‘\’ }, StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        sb.Append("\\" + segment);
    }
    return sb.ToString().Substring(2);

}
```

Comment: Good solution. Same idea, but more understandable code: `string query = string.Join(@"\\", input.Split(new char[] {'\\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));`