# Saving Path Name with Back Slash On The Server Issue

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm having a problem in saving photo path on the table column. When I click "Saved" on my code, I see that the column table(varchar) remove the back slash. That's a problem for me whenever I want to view the picture from my column photopath.

This is my save filepath that will send on the table when I click save.

```
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\MyPath\image-path\";
```

After I click saved, I see a wrong result on the column table(varchar)

```
C:MyPathimage-path
```

The saved path removed the Backslash. Any help Please

Comment: Possible Duplicate Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328782/how-to-add-directory-location-to-mysql-varchar

Comment: Sir please put your answer on the Answer Textarea and submit. I'll accept it as my answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to replace slash("\") with double slashes.

Try `saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\\MyPath\\image-path\\";`

If not working, Try

`string path1 =  @"C:\MyPath\image-path\";
string path2 = path1.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = path2;`

Comment: Thank you sir! God bless! Amen :D